# Contour labels in filled contours wrong

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, contourf

In the example below I want to add contour labels to a filled contour. I do the same for regular contours, and the result seems to be correct. For the filled contours, however, the labels are off. Is this a bug or did I misunderstand something?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

X,Z = numpy.meshgrid(range(5),range(5))
V = numpy.zeros([len(X),len(X[0])])
for kx in range(len(X[0])):
    for kz in range(len(X)):
        V[kz][kx] = X[kx][kz]


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
CS1 = ax1.contour(X,Z,V,range(5))
ax1.clabel(CS1,fontsize=16,colors='k')
cb1 = fig.colorbar(CS1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
CS2 = ax2.contourf(X,Z,V,range(5))
ax2.clabel(CS2,fontsize=16,colors='k')
cb2 = fig.colorbar(CS2)

fig.savefig('contour')
```

[image]

Comment: I *think* `clabel` only works with `contour`, not `contourf`. From the docs: "Adds labels to line contours in cs, where cs is a ContourSet object returned by contour"

Comment: thanks, that's probably it. as long as the colorbar is correct, i can live with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recent versions of Matplotlib have improved in this aspect. I ran your code on matplotlib 2.0.2, and got the following plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

X,Z = numpy.meshgrid(range(5),range(5))
V = numpy.zeros([len(X),len(X[0])])
for kx in range(len(X[0])):
    for kz in range(len(X)):
        V[kz][kx] = X[kx][kz]


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
CS1 = ax1.contour(X,Z,V,range(5))
ax1.clabel(CS1,fontsize=16,colors='k')
cb1 = fig.colorbar(CS1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
CS2 = ax2.contourf(X,Z,V,range(5))
ax2.clabel(CS2,fontsize=16,colors='k')
cb2 = fig.colorbar(CS2)

fig.savefig('contour')
```

[image]

This certainly looks better but it doesn't solve the problem completely. We want the labels on the filled contour plot to look like the labels in the contour line plot. Now as tom pointed out, we can't do that easily since `clabel` is designed to work with `contour` and not `contourf`. There is a not-so-neat workaround for this. What we can do is to first create the `contour` plot, whose labels can be easily manipulated with `clabel` function and then we fill this plot using `contourf`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

X,Z = numpy.meshgrid(range(5),range(5))
V = numpy.zeros([len(X),len(X[0])])
for kx in range(len(X[0])):
    for kz in range(len(X)):
        V[kz][kx] = X[kx][kz]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
CS1 = ax1.contour(X,Z,V,range(5))
ax1.clabel(CS1,fontsize=16,colors='k')
cb1 = fig.colorbar(CS1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
CS2 = ax2.contour(X,Z,V,range(5)) # Creating the contour plot
ax2.clabel(CS2,fontsize=16,colors='k')
CS3 = ax2.contourf(X,Z,V,range(5)) # Creating another filled contour plot on top
cb2 = fig.colorbar(CS3) # Display colorbar for filled contour plot

fig.savefig('contour')
```

[image]

I would still like these labels to be centred in the different regions of the plot, but I couldn't find a way to do that.