# Problem with labeling contour line with tricontourf() in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plot two contour graph in a figure with help of matplotlib library. When I try to add contour label in each line, I get a messed up graph like this: [Messed up contour graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH7SD.jpg)
Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import DataImportingContour as d
import matplotlib.cm as cm

def graphing_contour():
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
    #fig.set_size_inches(8, 5, forward=True)
    level_wallA = list(range(5, 44, 5))
    print(level_wallA)


    ax1.set_xticks(range(-5, 6))
    ax1.set_yticks([0.5, 1])
    ax1.set(xlabel='y/H', ylabel='z/H')
    ax1.set_title('Wall A')


    
    ax2.set_xticks(range(-5, 6))
    ax2.set_yticks([0.5, 1])
    ax2.set(xlabel='y/H', ylabel='z/H')
    ax2.set_title('Wall B')
    
    cs1 = ax1.tricontourf(d.dict['x0_list'], d.dict['y0_list'], d.dict['z0_list'], cmap=cm.YlOrBr, levels=8)
    cs2 = ax2.tricontourf(d.dict['x1_list'], d.dict['y1_list'], d.dict['z1_list'], cmap=cm.YlOrBr, levels=4)

    ax1.clabel(cs1, levels= level_wallA, inline=True)
    ax2.clabel(cs2, inline=True)

    fig.savefig('test.jpg')
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    graphing_contour()
```

I set cs1 and cs2 to ax1.tricontourf and ax2.tricontourf to get the parameter CS in clabel() in the guide of matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.clabel.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.clabel
For the result I do get the contour line label, but the graph is somewhat messed up and also the label is not clearly show.

Comment: `clabel` is meant for line contours, it messes up filled contours.  You might want to add both filled and unfilled contours.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568346/contour-labels-in-matplotlib-filled-contours-wrong. Also note that `fig.tight_layout()` (or `fig.savefig(..., bbox_inches='tight')`) usually helps to nicely layout the surrounding axes labels.